# android Flash black box on video on ICS

Tags: android, flash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I developped an application who allow to view flash video. 
For ergonomic reason, I put the flash video into a center webview. 
On android ICS on tablet, I have a black box on the right of the screen. 
Have you a fix to avoid black box on ICS on tablet?

It works perfectly under ICS on tablet!![image]